# JavaScript copy Input value to innerHTML on keyup (addEventListener)

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keyup

As the title says: I want to copy the input value to an html element (in realtime). I've tried something like this, but it's not working... THX in advance!

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="">

<p id="box"></p>


<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keyup', function () {

document.getElementById('box').innerhtml = document.getElementById('test').value;

});

</script>
```

Comment: Change innerhtml to `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Geuis said (post comment), your mistake is innerHTML (and not innerhtml), see : https://codesandbox.io/s/724r405wo1

I would encourage you to change your code to :

```
var box = document.getElementById('box')

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    box.innerHTML = event.target.value
});
```

So you do not query the dom every time.

Comment: OMG I'm ashamed, it was late... THX so far :D

Answer (score 0):

You must use the input value to get instant input. Like :

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = e.target.value
})
```

Comment: i think  `addEventListener('input', ... ` should be `addEventListener('change', ... `